# Can multiple Yoshis ride each other at the same time?

Tags: super-mario-bros-wonder

When two players play as Yoshi in local multiplayer, they are able to ride on each other's backs. If three or four players play as Yoshi, can they ride each other at the same time in a single stack of Yoshis?

Comment: "It's turtles all the way down!"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may expect this, the answer is no.

According to [Gamee8](https://game8.co/games/Super-Mario-Bros-Wonder/archives/430478):

> Unfortunately, if you are thinking of letting another Yoshi ride you while you're riding another Yoshi, the game does not allow for 3 Yoshis to ride each other.

Comment: I was tempted to make a humorous comment about "but that doesn't say you cannot stack 4 Yoshis, only that you cannot stack 3", but I think it's implied.

Comment: @Clockwork do you think it's better to clarify? Lol

Comment: Nah, unless you can put a stack of 2 Yoshis on top of another stack of 2 Yoshis, which I doubt.